# Get openstack helm running in a vm behind a proxy

Tags: virtualbox, openstack, kubernetes-helm

I have been working on getting a helm distribution running on a vm for some time. I have found conflicting arguments about it being possible or not due to virtualization layers, but here it goes.

I am working with a virtualbox ubuntu 16.04 with 16gb ram
following the guide at https://docs.openstack.org/openstack-helm/latest/install/developer/requirements-and-host-config.html

I am also working behind a proxy and I have added all the relevant proxy settings in accordance with https://docs.openstack.org/openstack-helm/latest/troubleshooting/proxy.html

When I run the command `make dev-deploy setup-host` it passes and has the following output:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
f6859822cc9a        gcr.io/google_containers/kube-apiserver-amd64            "kube-apiserver --se…"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes                           k8s_kube-apiserver_kube-apiserver-ram_kube-system_9b1ce48429c89e5c30202699d11086af_2
c18ec1473790        gcr.io/google_containers/kube-scheduler-amd64            "kube-scheduler --ad…"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes                           k8s_kube-scheduler_kube-scheduler-ram_kube-system_65a679e8f744d3d257f72713d3790c3b_2
2b631d5fb2a3        gcr.io/google_containers/etcd-amd64                      "etcd --listen-clien…"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes                           k8s_etcd_etcd-ram_kube-system_7278f85057e8bf5cb81c9f96d3b25320_2
5a8b005119e3        gcr.io/google_containers/kube-controller-manager-amd64   "kube-controller-man…"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes                           k8s_kube-controller-manager_kube-controller-manager-ram_kube-system_2150e730dce733115de72022e9130f4c_2
a1917416a6e1        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                 "/pause"                 17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes                           k8s_POD_kube-controller-manager-ram_kube-system_2150e730dce733115de72022e9130f4c_2
caa82c2f2e24        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                 "/pause"                 17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes                           k8s_POD_kube-scheduler-ram_kube-system_65a679e8f744d3d257f72713d3790c3b_2
183a2a436c5e        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                 "/pause"                 17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes                           k8s_POD_etcd-ram_kube-system_7278f85057e8bf5cb81c9f96d3b25320_3
a3fbddd01f99        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                 "/pause"                 17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes                           k8s_POD_kube-apiserver-ram_kube-system_9b1ce48429c89e5c30202699d11086af_2
```

But when I run the coomand `make dev-deploy k8s` if fails with:

```
TASK [deploy-kubeadm-aio-master : deploying kubernetes on master node] *********************************************
TASK [deploy-kubeadm-aio-common : performing deploy-kube action] ***************************************************
fatal: [local]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "+ '[' xdeploy-kube == xdeploy-kubelet ']'\n+ '[' xdeploy-kube == xdeploy-kube ']'\n+ '[' x '!=' x ']'\n+ '[' xdocker0 '!=' x ']'\n++ echo '{' '\"my_container_name\":' '\"kubeadm-deploy-kube\",' '\"user\":' '{' '\"uid\":' 1000, '\"gid\":' 1000, '\"home\":' '\"/home/nicolas\"' '},' '\"cluster\":' '{' '\"cni\":' '\"calico\"' '},' '\"kubelet\":' '{' '\"container_runtime\":' '\"docker\",' '\"net_support_linuxbridge\":' true, '\"pv_support_nfs\":' true, '\"pv_support_ceph\":' true '},' '\"helm\":' '{' '\"tiller_image\":' '\"gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.7.2\"' '},' '\"k8s\":' '{' '\"kubernetesVersion\":' '\"v1.9.3\",' '\"imageRepository\":' '\"gcr.io/google_containers\",' '\"certificatesDir\":' '\"/etc/kubernetes/pki\",' '\"selfHosted\":' '\"false\",' '\"api\":' '{' '\"bindPort\":' 6443 '},' '\"networking\":' '{' '\"dnsDomain\":' '\"cluster.local\",' '\"podSubnet\":' '\"192.168.0.0/16\",' '\"serviceSubnet\":' '\"10.96.0.0/12\"' '}' '}' '}'\n++ jq '.k8s.api += {\"advertiseAddressDevice\": \"docker0\"}'\n+ PLAYBOOK_VARS='{\n  \"my_container_name\": \"kubeadm-deploy-kube\",\n  \"user\": {\n    \"uid\": 1000,\n    \"gid\": 1000,\n    \"home\": \"/home/nicolas\"\n  },\n  \"cluster\": {\n    \"cni\": \"calico\"\n  },\n  \"kubelet\": {\n    \"container_runtime\": \"docker\",\n    \"net_support_linuxbridge\": true,\n    \"pv_support_nfs\": true,\n    \"pv_support_ceph\": true\n  },\n  \"helm\": {\n    \"tiller_image\": \"gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.7.2\"\n  },\n  \"k8s\": {\n    \"kubernetesVersion\": \"v1.9.3\",\n    \"imageRepository\": \"gcr.io/google_containers\",\n    \"certificatesDir\": \"/etc/kubernetes/pki\",\n    \"selfHosted\": \"false\",\n    \"api\": {\n      \"bindPort\": 6443,\n      \"advertiseAddressDevice\": \"docker0\"\n    },\n    \"networking\": {\n      \"dnsDomain\": \"cluster.local\",\n      \"podSubnet\": \"192.168.0.0/16\",\n      \"serviceSubnet\": \"10.96.0.0/12\"\n    }\n  }\n}'\n+ exec ansible-playbook /opt/playbooks/kubeadm-aio-deploy-master.yaml --inventory=/opt/playbooks/inventory.ini --inventory=/opt/playbooks/vars.yaml '--extra-vars={\n  \"my_container_name\": \"kubeadm-deploy-kube\",\n  \"user\": {\n    \"uid\": 1000,\n    \"gid\": 1000,\n    \"home\": \"/home/nicolas\"\n  },\n  \"cluster\": {\n    \"cni\": \"calico\"\n  },\n  \"kubelet\": {\n    \"container_runtime\": \"docker\",\n    \"net_support_linuxbridge\": true,\n    \"pv_support_nfs\": true,\n    \"pv_support_ceph\": true\n  },\n  \"helm\": {\n    \"tiller_image\": \"gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.7.2\"\n  },\n  \"k8s\": {\n    \"kubernetesVersion\": \"v1.9.3\",\n    \"imageRepository\": \"gcr.io/google_containers\",\n    \"certificatesDir\": \"/etc/kubernetes/pki\",\n    \"selfHosted\": \"false\",\n    \"api\": {\n      \"bindPort\": 6443,\n      \"advertiseAddressDevice\": \"docker0\"\n    },\n    \"networking\": {\n      \"dnsDomain\": \"cluster.local\",\n      \"podSubnet\": \"192.168.0.0/16\",\n      \"serviceSubnet\": \"10.96.0.0/12\"\n    }\n  }\n}'\n\nPLAY [all] 
*********************************************************************\n\nTASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************\nok: 
[/mnt/rootfs]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : storing node hostname] ***************************\nok: [/mnt/rootfs]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : setup directorys on host] ************************\nok: [/mnt/rootfs] => (item=/etc/kubernetes)\nchanged: [/mnt/rootfs] => (item=/etc/kubernetes/pki)\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : generating initial admin token] ******************\nchanged: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : storing initial admin token] *********************\nok: [/mnt/rootfs]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : kubelet | copying config to host] ****************\nchanged: [/mnt/rootfs]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | certs | ca] ********************\nchanged: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | certs | apiserver] *************\nchanged: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | certs | apiserver-kubelet-client] ***\nchanged: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | certs | sa] ********************\nchanged: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | certs | front-proxy-ca] ********\nchanged: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | certs | front-proxy-client] ****\nchanged: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | kubeconfig | admin] ************\nchanged: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | kubeconfig | kubelet] **********\nchanged: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | kubeconfig | controller-manager] ***\nchanged: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | kubeconfig | scheduler] ********\nchanged: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : generating etcd static manifest] *****************\nchanged: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | controlplane | apiserver] ******\nchanged: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | controlplane | controller-manager] ***\nchanged: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | controlplane | scheduler] ******\nchanged: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : wait for kube api] *******************************\nFAILED - RETRYING: wait for kube api (120 retries left).\nchanged: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]\n\nTASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : wait for node to come online] ********************\nFAILED
```

and then:

```
TASK [deploy-kubeadm-aio-common : dumping logs for deploy-kube action] *********************************************
ok: [local] => {
    "out.stdout_lines": [
        "", 
        "PLAY [all] *********************************************************************", 
        "", 
        "TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************", 
        "ok: [/mnt/rootfs]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : storing node hostname] ***************************", 
        "ok: [/mnt/rootfs]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : setup directorys on host] ************************", 
        "ok: [/mnt/rootfs] => (item=/etc/kubernetes)", 
        "changed: [/mnt/rootfs] => (item=/etc/kubernetes/pki)", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : generating initial admin token] ******************", 
        "changed: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : storing initial admin token] *********************", 
        "ok: [/mnt/rootfs]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : kubelet | copying config to host] ****************", 
        "changed: [/mnt/rootfs]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | certs | ca] ********************", 
        "changed: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | certs | apiserver] *************", 
        "changed: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | certs | apiserver-kubelet-client] ***", 
        "changed: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | certs | sa] ********************", 
        "changed: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | certs | front-proxy-ca] ********", 
        "changed: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | certs | front-proxy-client] ****", 
        "changed: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | kubeconfig | admin] ************", 
        "changed: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | kubeconfig | kubelet] **********", 
        "changed: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | kubeconfig | controller-manager] ***", 
        "changed: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | kubeconfig | scheduler] ********", 
        "changed: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : generating etcd static manifest] *****************", 
        "changed: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | controlplane | apiserver] ******", 
        "changed: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | controlplane | controller-manager] ***", 
        "changed: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : master | deploy | controlplane | scheduler] ******", 
        "changed: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : wait for kube api] *******************************", 
        "FAILED - RETRYING: wait for kube api (120 retries left).", 
        "changed: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]", 
        "", 
        "TASK [deploy-kubeadm-master : wait for node to come online] ********************", 
        "FAILED - RETRYING: wait for node to come online (120 retries left).", 
        "FAILED - RETRYING: wait for node to come online (119 retries left).", 
...
        "FAILED - RETRYING: wait for node to come online (2 retries left).", 
        "FAILED - RETRYING: wait for node to come online (1 retries left).", 
        "fatal: [/mnt/rootfs -> 127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {\"attempts\": 120, \"changed\": true, \"cmd\": \"kubectl get node \\\"Ram\\\" --no-headers | gawk '{ print $2 }' | grep -q '\\\\(^Ready\\\\)\\\\|\\\\(^NotReady\\\\)'\", \"delta\": \"0:00:01.188128\", \"end\": \"2018-04-05 17:06:51.647344\", \"msg\": \"non-zero return code\", \"rc\": 1, \"start\": \"2018-04-05 17:06:50.459216\", \"stderr\": \"Error from server (NotFound): nodes \\\"Ram\\\" not found\", \"stderr_lines\": [\"Error from server (NotFound): nodes \\\"Ram\\\" not found\"], \"stdout\": \"\", \"stdout_lines\": []}", 
        "\tto retry, use: --limit @/opt/playbooks/kubeadm-aio-deploy-master.retry", 
        "", 
        "PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************", 
        "/mnt/rootfs                : ok=21   changed=18   unreachable=0    failed=1   "
    ]
}

TASK [deploy-kubeadm-aio-common : exiting if deploy-kube action failed] ********************************************
fatal: [local]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "exit 1", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in this step of the Ansible playbook when deploying an AIO openstack with Helm on a VM.

In this step a number of docker containers are created. (You can verify this with "docker ps" in another terminal. It takes some time)

```
ubuntu@xxx:~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
07ee2d56038a        ac5f7ee9ae7e                 "/tiller"                44 seconds ago       Up 43 seconds                           k8s_tiller_tiller-deploy-7df7fbdd9c-dwzs8_kube-system_28952c16-1d8d-11e9-9ac4-fa163e98e40b_0
e49ef4eaee2c        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 46 seconds ago       Up 45 seconds                           k8s_POD_tiller-deploy-7df7fbdd9c-dwzs8_kube-system_28952c16-1d8d-11e9-9ac4-fa163e98e40b_0
282cbd3089a6        fed89e8b4248                 "/sidecar --v=2 --lo…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_sidecar_kube-dns-7485c77cc-wr88r_kube-system_1c2a3761-1d8d-11e9-9ac4-fa163e98e40b_0
b93e2ab03f6c        459944ce8cc4                 "/dnsmasq-nanny -v=2…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_dnsmasq_kube-dns-7485c77cc-wr88r_kube-system_1c2a3761-1d8d-11e9-9ac4-fa163e98e40b_0
4148856fcdd4        512cd7425a73                 "/kube-dns --domain=…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_kubedns_kube-dns-7485c77cc-wr88r_kube-system_1c2a3761-1d8d-11e9-9ac4-fa163e98e40b_0
14b8cd3cd089        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_POD_kube-dns-7485c77cc-wr88r_kube-system_1c2a3761-1d8d-11e9-9ac4-fa163e98e40b_0
3bab5bea7b6e        6f1a824b2c81                 "/usr/bin/kube-contr…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_calico-kube-controllers_calico-kube-controllers-6bccb8d477-qbk55_kube-system_089abbd3-1d8d-11e9-9ac4-fa163e98e40b_0
f6916bba8ccb        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_POD_calico-kube-controllers-6bccb8d477-qbk55_kube-system_089abbd3-1d8d-11e9-9ac4-fa163e98e40b_0
80cfd3f75475        a89b45f36d5e                 "start_runit"            About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_calico-node_calico-node-d5n8s_kube-system_0890d2d2-1d8d-11e9-9ac4-fa163e98e40b_0
9b8c7f4e9655        58c02f00d03b                 "/usr/local/bin/etcd…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_calico-etcd_calico-etcd-d658p_kube-system_088f6c7e-1d8d-11e9-9ac4-fa163e98e40b_0
d78105adb690        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_POD_calico-node-d5n8s_kube-system_0890d2d2-1d8d-11e9-9ac4-fa163e98e40b_0
7a58c798a05a        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_POD_calico-etcd-d658p_kube-system_088f6c7e-1d8d-11e9-9ac4-fa163e98e40b_0
5a8b67e4f12d        3eb53757e3db                 "/usr/local/bin/kube…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-fc557_kube-system_01792fcc-1d8d-11e9-9ac4-fa163e98e40b_0
0cf582074588        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_POD_kube-proxy-fc557_kube-system_01792fcc-1d8d-11e9-9ac4-fa163e98e40b_0
c51f0e9ab095        a8706603e59d                 "kube-scheduler --ad…"   2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes                            k8s_kube-scheduler_kube-scheduler-openstack---helm_kube-system_4cfd2774e591ce0cf177c635d6ca6850_0
c1bdb76ab9cf        52920ad46f5b                 "etcd --listen-clien…"   2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes                            k8s_etcd_etcd-openstack---helm_kube-system_1a6fe3b688c5f1cbaa41d4e4e0dc702b_0
1d39d3d9cb39        a0e5065bdee0                 "kube-controller-man…"   2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes                            k8s_kube-controller-manager_kube-controller-manager-openstack---helm_kube-system_7f18c2dbce121d9cbf120054643f96cf_0
e6cf7228793e        f8187c0f74c8                 "kube-apiserver --fe…"   2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes                            k8s_kube-apiserver_kube-apiserver-openstack---helm_kube-system_ef303a0f16f6d02a535b073b1ce77bd1_0
16ca266396fc        18be53808701                 "dnsmasq --keep-in-f…"   2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes                            k8s_osh-dns-redirector_osh-dns-redirector-openstack---helm_kube-system_b4dcd4cd9d071cf5c953824f3630b532_0
ff4850d1148d        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes                            k8s_POD_kube-scheduler-openstack---helm_kube-system_4cfd2774e591ce0cf177c635d6ca6850_0
093826e65165        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes                            k8s_POD_kube-controller-manager-openstack---helm_kube-system_7f18c2dbce121d9cbf120054643f96cf_0
498e4e03c00b        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes                            k8s_POD_kube-apiserver-openstack---helm_kube-system_ef303a0f16f6d02a535b073b1ce77bd1_0
d31b3720f9d2        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes                            k8s_POD_etcd-openstack---helm_kube-system_1a6fe3b688c5f1cbaa41d4e4e0dc702b_0
fb5c6c8adec0        k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes                            k8s_POD_osh-dns-redirector-openstack---helm_kube-system_b4dcd4cd9d071cf5c953824f3630b532_0
```

When I re-tried to deploy in another VM with more resources the playbook could finnish without errors.

```
TASK [deploy-kubeadm-aio-common : performing deploy-kubelet action] ************************************************************************************************************************************

changed: [local]

TASK [deploy-kubeadm-aio-common : removing container for deploy-kubelet action] ************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [local]

TASK [deploy-kubeadm-aio-master : deploying kubernetes on master node] *********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [deploy-kubeadm-aio-common : performing deploy-kube action] ***************************************************************************************************************************************


changed: [local]

TASK [deploy-kubeadm-aio-common : removing container for deploy-kube action] ***************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [local]
 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: nodes

PLAY [nodes] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
local                      : ok=18   changed=13   unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I'm not 100% sure but it could be a resource issue. Maybe the containers aren't created fast enough on your VM and therefore the script returns these failures:

"FAILED - RETRYING: wait for node to come online (1 retries left).",

As you can see in my output, I have more containers running.

**Working VM specs**:

- 8 VCPUS
- 16GB RAM
- 60GB disk

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error.
Problem is simple: your hostname doesn't match to this one that Ansible want to run a job.

E.g.:

```
root@k8s1:~# hostname
k8s1
```

So in /etc/hosts, it add:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX k8s1.XXX.test k8s1
```

Solution:

```
echo "k8s1.XXX.test" > /etc/hostname
hostname "k8s1.XXX.test"
reboot
```